# jQuery: changing background color without making permanent (currently it disabled my css :hover)

Tags: jquery, css, background, hover, background-color

I currently have a set of divs (buttons) that all hover various colors using css. When one of this divs is pressed, I used jQuery to make the color permanent and reverted the color of all other divs back to default.

However, it seems that once this is done, the :hover color doesn't work anymore. Am I approaching the jQuery wrong? How can I fix this. Here is an example:

#### EDIT

I am posting a jsfiddle to better explain. You will see that when you first scan your mouse across the divs, they hover different colors. And if you click either div 1 or div 2 (the others won't work, didn't bother doing the jQuery code for the fiddle for all of them), the div keeps it's color and any other one reverts to original. HOWEVER, this then disables the :hover pseudo class I have in my CSS. I need help fixing this.

http://jsfiddle.net/P3Ckk/143/

What is the best solution to this?

Comment: I'd rather use a single class for all your DIV elements. That's what `classes` are for, right? I really cannot imagine your issue, can you create a http://jsbin.com  demo? or just post a HTML would be fine

Comment: The tiles themselves all hover different colors and change to different colors. If they were all the same color, yes, I'd just make them identical classes. Except for the content divs that I am toggling through since they must be more specific, but those divs aren't important for the problem at hand. I'll get a jsfiddle up. Hold on.

Comment: Which browser are you using? You can use `data` attribute or `rel` attribute.

Comment: Working example here: http://jsfiddle.net/P3Ckk/145/ :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Working Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/P3Ckk/145/

I would rather do this way:

**HTML**

```
<div id='mainIconTile1' class="mainIconTile">
</div>

<div id='mainIconTile2' class="mainIconTile">
</div>

<div id='mainIconTile3' class="mainIconTile">
</div>

<div id='mainIconTile4' class="mainIconTile">
</div>

<div id='mainIconTile5' class="mainIconTile">
</div>

<div id='mainIconTile6' class="mainIconTile">
</div>

<div id='mainContentTile1'>
    1
</div>

<div id='mainContentTile2'>
    2
</div>

<div id='mainContentTile3'>
    3
</div>

<div id='mainContentTile4'>
    4
</div>

<div id='mainContentTile5'>
    5
</div>

<div id='mainContentTile6'>
    6
</div>
```

​**CSS**

```
.mainIconTile {
    background:#888888;                
    width:20px;
    height:20px;
    margin:1px;
    float:left;
}

#mainIconTile1:hover, #mainIconTile1.active {
    background:#5aa02c;
}

#mainIconTile2:hover, #mainIconTile2.active {
    background:red;
}


#mainIconTile3:hover, #mainIconTile3.active {
    background:blue;
}


#mainIconTile4:hover, #mainIconTile4.active {
    background:green;
}

#mainIconTile5:hover, #mainIconTile5.active {
    background:pink;
}

#mainIconTile6:hover, #mainIconTile5.active {
    background:brown;
}

#mainContentTile1 {
    background:orange;
    height:50px;
    width:50px;
    float:left;
    clear:left;
    display:none;
}

#mainContentTile2 {
    background:#e8e8e8;
    height:50px;
    width:50px;
    float:left;
    clear:left;

}

#mainContentTile3 {
    background:#e8e8e8;
    height:50px;
    width:50px;
    float:left;
    clear:left;
    display:none;
}

#mainContentTile4 {
    background:#e8e8e8;
    height:50px;
    width:50px;
    float:left;
    clear:left;
    display:none;
}

#mainContentTile5 {
    background:#e8e8e8;
    height:50px;
    width:50px;
    float:left;
    clear:left;
    display:none;
}

#mainContentTile6 {
    background:#e8e8e8;
    height:50px;
    width:50px;
    float:left;
    clear:left;
    display:none;
}
```

​

**JavaScript**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('div[id*="mainIconTile"]').click(function() {
        var theId = $(this).attr("id");
        $(".mainIconTile").removeClass('active');
        $("#" + theId).addClass('active');
        $('.mainContentTile:visible').hide(0, function(){
            $('#mainContentTile' + theId.substring(12)).show();
        });
    });
});
```

### Working Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/P3Ckk/145/

Comment: Thank you for that. Much simpler CSS. Hopefully the jQuery you have works better than mine that has failed me. :(

Comment: Thanks Praveen! That's perfect. Now time to figure out some of that code that I'm unfamiliar with so I can learn from and replicate what you've done in the future. Thanks!!!

Comment: Praveen... quick if still around. So it seems one problem I'm having with my code is that I actually am using more unique identifiers than 1 - 6 I have in the fiddle. When I change these #s to words, it breaks. What piece of the jQuery is specifically calling out this 1, 2, 3 part of the id? And is there any way for me to have it reference the word I have at the end instead? Or am I better off just using #s? The words are there because they help for readability of the code.

Comment: Don't change the `ID` then. Give some more classes. I have tried my level best to find only the changing thingy. Okay, in that case, give a number at the end, and make sure it is with the matching div's class / id.

Answer (score 1):

I have no idea why this is happening (pretty weird), but when I used:

```
$("div#mainIconTile1").hover(function () {
   $(this).css("background", "#5aa02c");
}, function () {
   $(this).css("background", "#888");
});
```

it worked! So you may want to rely on jQuery hover in this case if CSS doesn't work.
Of course there is also the solution of adding/removing css classes.

Comment: Check out my answer buddy. This doesn't work in all the cases. You need to put this code almost 6 times or even n times!!!